# How does SVN keep track of which repository a folder is commited to?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've taken over a former employee's workstation that has source code committed to 2 different svn repositories depending on what folder the code is in.  TortoiseSVN is used in windows explorer.

How does TortoiseSVN keeps track of which SVN repository is associated with each folder? Where is the configuration file located?

Answer (score 1):

That information is kept in the (hidden) `.svn` folder(s). The information within is not intended to be viewed or manipulated outside of subversion tools. Working copies of 1.6 and earlier have a `.svn` folder inside of each folder. Subversion 1.7 working copies and above have one `.svn' folder in the root of the working copy.

[Inside the working copy (Subversion 1.6)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.developer.insidewc.html)

Using TortoiseSVN, you can right-click on a folder, select Properties, then the Subversion tab. This will show you the subversion information about the folder, such as where it points to.

Answer (score 0):

In the local folder in your machine there is a `.svn` folder (only in the main folder if you are using Subversion 1.7.2 and above OR in all sub folders as well) if a folder is bound to any SVN repository. This folder stores the mapping.

Unless there is no file in your working copy is locked explicitly by calling, `svn lock`, there is nothing related to this in SVN server. So in that case, you can just delete that `.svn` folders and this local working copy folder will no more be mapped to the server repository.

Comment: The SVN server *does* keep track of which working copy is holding a lock on files. So if you have anything locked, you need to release those locks before deleting the `.svn` directory or else someone else will have to manually break it later.

Comment: SVN never locks a normal file in the server side for any operation unless that is locked explicitly using [`svn:needs-lock`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html) and that is not getting affected if we delete`.svn` folder . The local working copy file just gets locked up in locally if any SVN operation like update etc. broken incomplete. That local file lock can be released by an `svn:cleanup` command. Or else even you can commit from a different working copy of the same repository as well. So that is also affecting anything in server if we delete `.svn` folder.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote. I didn't say *anything* about local locking. Only that if you claim a lock, a unique identifier for your working copy is recorded on the server as having a lock on that file. If you delete the `.svn` directory, that unique ID is gone client-side, but the server has it associated with the file. I've been dealing with this frequently lately as people have had their PCs replaced and didn't release their locks beforehand - so I have to manually break the lock.

Comment: Oh, this was new to me. I never thought that `svn lock` will make problem if working copy is corrupted or lost. I mean that is really weird, they should keep track of the lock based on user instead of these tokens. Thanks for correction. I am just updating the answer so.

Comment: There are [three kinds of locks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) in Subversion. When you use `svn lock`, the working copy has to be tracked instead of the user because one user could have multiple WCs and you only want to allow commits from one of those.